# PHP OOP coding conventions

Tags: php, oop, convention

I'm brand new at OOP PHP and i would like to get as many of the coding conventions right as fast as possible. I made this tiny guestbook script, and i would like to know if there's anything not done as it should.

Index.php:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "oop";
$host = "localhost";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include("views/gaestebog.php");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Guestbook.php, the class:

```
<?php
class Gaestebog {

    public function __contruct() {

    }

    public function getPosts() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gaestebog");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row['navn'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row['besked'].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
    }

    public function addPost($navn, $besked) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gaestebog VALUES('', '$navn', '$besked')");
    }
}
?>
```

and guestbook.php, the view:

```
<?php
include("classes/Gaestebog.php");
$gaestebog = new Gaestebog();
if (isset($_POST['opret'])) {
    $navn = $_POST['navn'];
    $besked = $_POST['besked'];
    $gaestebog->addPost($navn, $besked);
}
?>
<table>
    <?php
    $gaestebog->getPosts();
    ?>
</table>

<hr />

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Navn:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="navn" value="Patrick" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Besked:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="besked" value="Hej med dig !!" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="opret" value="Opret" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the PHP manual online about your use of database operations for MySQL for example `mysql_query()` is no longer suggested http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php one of the alternatives is to use the `mysqli` interface with is OOP.

Comment: instead of using `mysql` go for `mysqli` or `PDO`. Use parameterized query. make a use of database abstraction class instead of using core database functions in your classes. Thats all I can think of now

Comment: When i use mysqli, should i be creating a new object inside every class of the mysqli connection?

Comment: @PatrickReck: No, you create one instance, and pass it around you objects/methods.

Answer (score 4):

This is often called procedural programming with outdated libraries:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);
```

And that was only the beginning of your script. Maybe it's better you don't focus so much on fancy programming terms but instead just get the work done.

Example *`guestbook.php`*:

```
<?php
require('bootstrap.php');

$page = new Htmlpage('My Guestbook');
$page->start($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$gaestebog = new Gaestebog();

echo '<table border="1">';

foreach ($gaestebog->getPosts() as $post)
{
    $row = new Htmlencoded($post);

    echo <<<OUT
            <tr>
                <td>$row['navn']</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$row['besked']</td>
            </tr>
OUT;
}
echo '</table>';

$page->closeRequest();
?>
```

Otherwise if you want to learn about object oriented programming, use object interfaces and practice, practice, practice.

Start with something simple, like a *form field*. Not with a whole script.

Comment: What the hell is "Gaestebog"?

Comment: @Simon_eQ: Did you mean: *Wat de hel is "Gaestebog"?* ? :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the first, and most obvious thing to note is your vulnerability to **SQL injection**.

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Also, it's considered good practice to separate logic from presentation (i.e. PHP from HTML).

Comment: How would i separate it even more than i've done here?

Comment: @PatrickReck: Well, you need very little PHP code on your **view** or **template** (that's what it's called). Form processing, heavy business logic, database interactions, those should be on their own files, with zero HTML output on them.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of points:

- Don't use the deprecated mysql library, try PDO or MySQLi instead
- `__contruct()` has a typo, should be `__construct()`.
- Don't return raw HTML from get methods such as `getPosts()`, instead return an array of posts and let the view create HTML if that's the output you want
- Protect against, SQL Injection, your `INSERT` query is vulnerable